# Looping an array with php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a code like this

```
$events = array(


array(
    "id" => 101,
    "start_date" => "2016-04-05 08:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2016-04-09 09:00:00",
    "text" => "text1",
    "rec_type" => "week_2___3,5",
    "event_pid" => null,
    "event_length" => 3600
),

array(
    "id" => 102,
    "start_date" => "2016-04-06 12:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2016-04-06 18:00:00",
    "text" => "text2",
    "rec_type" => "",
    "event_pid" => null,
    "event_length" => null
),

array(
    "id" => 103,
    "start_date" => "2016-04-07 12:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2016-04-07 18:00:00",
    "text" => "text3",
    "rec_type" => "",
    "event_pid" => null,
    "event_length" => null
),

array(
    "id" => 104,
    "start_date" => "2016-04-08 12:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2016-04-08 18:00:00",
    "text" => "text4",
    "rec_type" => "",
    "event_pid" => null,
    "event_length" => null
)
);
```

Now I should get some data from MySQL and make this dynamically but maintaining the variable `$events` the same as there.

I have tried in some way with while and for, but maybe I made some mistake in the syntax.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. What exactly is the relation between this array and your SQL query?

Comment: The data from mysql, do you want to combine it with the above array and use `$events` to store both arrays ? or you just want codes to iterate over the above array ?

Comment: @andre3wap I want to combine the data with the array, replacing a static example with a dynamic one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$events = //your array 
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM tbl');

while ($row = $sth->fetchRow()) {
   array_push($events,$row)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for, but his question is very vague.  I was under the impression he wanted to loop through the array he has already.

Comment: agree the question is not clear, but looking at the array, it seems like it contains rows and columns and is returned from a database call that`s why I posted a likely answer.anyway thanks for the notice

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean.  Both are viable I guess.  OP needs to be more clear.

Comment: no that is just a static example, I think Luke Park is right. That's just the code I had and it is working...but I just don't know how to change it in a dynamic code, generated every time dynamically, and make that $event exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

To loop through an array within an array?

```
foreach($arr1 as $arr2) {
    foreach($arr2 as $val) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers

I'll try to be more specific as asked by someone (i'm not english motherlanguage, excuse me if I cant explain my problem very well), in the meantime I'll try some of the answers,

that $event has to be send in a class, the code continue in this way

```
$events = array(


array(
    "id" => 101,
    "start_date" => "2016-04-05 08:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2016-04-09 09:00:00",
    "text" => "text1",
    "rec_type" => "week_2___3,5",
    "event_pid" => null,
    "event_length" => 3600
)


);


$title = "some_title";
require_once("../../ical/codebase/class.php");
$export = new ICalExporter();
$export->setTitle($title);
$ical = $export->toICal($events);
```

and i have a table in the database made in the same way of the array, with the same fields, and every calendar has more event, but i need a $event that can be accepted by the class, like that but generated every time automatically, that's just a static code, the working example I had. 
I think its just a problem to find the right syntax, but its pretty complicated for me I don't know why, I usually can find suddenly the right solution )...anyways checking later if there are further answers

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be something like this, but it's not working yet...

```
$q_events = dbquery("select from * calendars where id_event = 1");


$events = array();
$i=0;

while ($q_ev=mysql_fetch_array($q_events)) {
            $events[$i]['id'] = $q_ev['event_id'];
            $events[$i]['start_date'] = $q_ev['start_date'];
            $events[$i]['end_date'] = $q_ev['end_date'];
            $events[$i]['text'] = $q_ev['text'];
            $events[$i]['rec_type'] = $q_ev['rec_type'];
            $events[$i]['event_pid'] = $q_ev['event_pid'];
            $events[$i]['event_length'] = $q_ev['event_length'];            
    $i++;   
        }


$title = $_GET['idstruttura']."_".changeLetters($_GET['nomestruttura']);
require_once("../../ical/codebase/class.php");
$export = new ICalExporter();
$export->setTitle($title);
$ical = $export->toICal($events);
```

if I do print_r on the array after the query the result is like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 413 [start_date] => 2016-02-15 00:00:00 [end_date] => 2016-02-21 00:00:00 [text] => fafafa [rec_type] => week_2___3,5 [event_pid] => 213 [event_length] => 518400 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 408 [start_date] => 2016-01-11 00:00:00 [end_date] => 2016-01-18 00:00:00 [text] => evento_da_pannello [rec_type] => week_2___3,5 [event_pid] => 213 [event_length] => 604800 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 410 [start_date] => 2015-12-28 00:00:00 [end_date] => 2015-12-31 00:00:00 [text] => aaa [rec_type] => week_2___3,5 [event_pid] => 213 [event_length] => 259200 ) )
```

it looks correct, strange

Answer (score 0):

i have tried again with the code in the last post, making just some little change not regarding the part of the array, and fortunately it works

thanks to everyone for support, and to this wonderful website, I have been following for many years, even if I was just a reader )